# Именование файлов по порядку при загрузке на сервер

Tags: php

Как в скрипте массовой загрузки файлов на сервер прописать код, чтобы генерировались имена по порядку начиная с 1 (единицы)?

Как в скрипте массовой загрузки файлов на сервер прописать код, чтобы имена загружаемых файлов генерировались таким образом: 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg ... и т.д. с увеличением на 1 каждый раз.  Знаю, что можно использовать инкремент ($a**++**), только куда его здесь воткнуть, не догоняю.

Код скрипта такой:

```
<? //Данные для ведения логов
$result = array();

$result['time'] = date('r');
$result['addr'] = substr_replace(gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), '******', 0, 6);
$result['agent'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

if (count($_GET)) {
    $result['get'] = $_GET;
}
if (count($_POST)) {
    $result['post'] = $_POST;
}
if (count($_FILES)) {
    $result['files'] = $_FILES;
}

if (file_exists('script.log') && filesize('script.log') > 102400) {
    unlink('script.log');
}
//Запись данных в лог файл 
$log = @fopen('script.log', 'a');
if ($log) {
    fputs($log, print_r($result, true) . "\n---\n");
    fclose($log);
}

//Изначально у нас нет ошибок 
$error = false;

//Определяем, был ли файл загружен при помощи HTTP POST 
if (!isset($_FILES['Filedata']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'])) {
    $error = 'Invalid Upload';
}

//Проверяем размер загружаемых файлов 
if (!$error && $_FILES['Filedata']['size'] > 2 * 1024 * 1024){
    $error = 'Размер загружаемого файла не должен превышать 2 Мб';
}

//При желание вы можете добавить другие проверки

//Если появились ошибки возвращаем их 
if ($error) {

    $return = array(
        'status' => '0',
        'error' => $error
    );

} else {//Если ошибок нет

    $return = array(
        'status' => '1',
        'name' => $_FILES['Filedata']['name']
    );

    //Получаем информацию о загруженном файле
    $info = @getimagesize($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']);

    if ($info) {
        $return['width'] = $info[0];//ширина картинки в пикселях
        $return['height'] = $info[1];//высота в пиксилях
    }
    $filename = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];//Определяем имя файла
    $ext = substr($filename,strpos($filename,'.'),strlen($filename)-1);//Определяем расширение файла
    $new = date("Ymd")."_".rand(1000,9999).$ext;//Генерируем новое имя файла во избежании совпадения названий
    $return['new'] = $new;//Возвращаем имя нового файла

    if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], '../uploads/'.$new)) //Загружаем файл с новым именем. 
    //Не забудьте установить на каталог uploads права на запись 755 или 777
    {
        $return = array(
        'status' => '0',
        'error' => 'Загрузка не удалась'
        );
    }
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['response']) && $_REQUEST['response'] == 'xml') {
    // header('Content-type: text/xml');

    // Really dirty, use DOM and CDATA section!
    echo '<response>';
    foreach ($return as $key => $value) {
        echo "<$key><![CDATA[$value]]></$key>";
    }
    echo '</response>';
} else {
    // header('Content-type: application/json');

    echo json_encode($return);

}

?>
```

Comment: Извиняюсь спросить, а зачем это нужно? Чем произвольные имена плохи?

Comment: Это нужно, чтобы работал другой скрипт который, будет выводить закачанные картинки и из заданой дериктории по порядку 1, 2, 3 и т.д

Comment: проще тогда делать рандомные имена, и писать, допустим, в текстовый файл, а вторым скриптом, читать файл и будет в результате массив имен файлов - делай что хочешь с ним.
А если постоянно прибавлять 1, то вам перед каждой загрузкой надо сканировать директорию и искать имя последнего.
Через файл будет гораздо проще. Ну или в крайнем случае вести текстовый файл и перед загрузкой открывать его и смотреть какое число было последним, ну а после загрузки обновлять эту цифру (т.е. не вести полный список файлов, а записывать только имя последнего)

Comment: Тогда уж в БД их проще заносить с датой и принадлежностью к записи. Заодно и сортировка адекватная будет.

Comment: Ну а если нет БД... :)

Comment: а я бы завел табличку в бд и всем загруженным файлам присваивал случайные имена(например некий хеш), а в таблице фиксировал оригинальное имя файла и имя под которым он был сохранен и где

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//$new = date("Ymd")."_".rand(1000,9999).$ext;//Генерируем новое имя файла во избежании совпадения названий
if (!file_exists('lastnum.txt')) file_put_contents('lastnum.txt', '0');
$N = intval(file_get_contents('lastnum.txt'))+1;
file_put_contents('lastnum.txt', $N);
$new = $N.$ext;
```

Таким образом номер следующего всегда будет (`номер_предыдущего+1`), независимо от расширения.

Answer (score 1):

```
$m = glob('../uploads/*.' . $ext);
$n = explode('/', $m[sizeof($m)-1]);
$n = $n[sizeof($n)-1];
$n = (int) substr($n, 0, strpos($n, '.'));
++$n; // <- вот нужный номер
```

Comment: Если только из серединки не удалят и файлов других нет) Хотя мой тоже "скакать" будет в первом случае.

Comment: Пускай удаляют - мы берем последний номер и увеличиваем его на 1. И другие файлы тоже можно, потому что ищется *.$ext .

Comment: Ну имелось в виду, что, например, при наличии 1.jpg и bg.jpg - bg.jpg по сортировке будет дальше, соответственно, ((int)'bg'+1)=1.

Comment: А, в этом плане. =) Тогда да, придется дописывать функцию и проверять, чему равен номер.

Answer (score 0):

вместо

```
$new = date("Ymd")."_".rand(1000,9999).$ext;
```

напиши

```
$n++;
$new = $n.$ext;
```

Comment: Пробовал такую конструкцию, присваивает всем файлам 1 и получается такое дело: 1.jpg, 1.gif и все.